# Eclipse Pydev Installation Issue

Tags: python-3.x, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, pydev

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/53ogR.png)When I try to install Pydev I get the following Error

PyDev for Eclipse 7.2.0.201903251948 (org.python.pydev.feature.feature.group 7.2.0.201903251948) requires 'org.eclipse.ui 0.0.0' but it could not be found

How to fix it?

Comment: What version of Eclipse are you trying to install this in? Show us a longer version of the error log.

Comment: I am using Eclipse Indigo. I have attached an image of the error above

Comment: Eclipse Indigo is **8** years old, far too old for the current version of pydev. The current version of Eclipse is 2019-03.

Comment: ok.I didn't verify. Thank you